# Why is CDATA wrapped inline Javascript empty in TYPO3 CMS 9.5?

Tags: typo3, fluid, cdata, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

We've created a 3rd party extension for TYPO3. After upgrading to 9.5 we now get a `PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [...]/typo3_src-9.5.9/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/Parser/TemplateProcessor/NamespaceDetectionTemplateProcessor.php line 180`.

After some web research we found out that the problem is inline Javascript and you only can fix it by using right CDATA wrapping (more: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/88615)

So we've tried (according to the manuel https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-extbasefluid/master/en-us/Fluid/ThingsToKnow/JsAndInline.html):

```
<script>
    <![CDATA[
        (function($){
            alert('test');
        })(jQuery);
    ]]>
</script>
```

But now everything between the CDATA Wrap completely disappears in the frontend return. Also if we put the script tags in between the CDATA as well.

And that also don't work:

```
<f:format.cdata>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      (function($){
        alert('test');
      })(jQuery);
   </script>
</f:format.cdata>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to TYPO3 CMS **9.5.10** LTS fixed all the problems we have.

Comment: I don't understand how that could fix the problem when the standalone fluid parser still removes the sections.

Answer (score 0):

Try either:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   <f:format.cdata>
      (function($){
        alert('test');
      })(jQuery);
   </f:format.cdata>
</script>
```

or

```
<f:format.raw>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      (function($){
        alert('test');
      })(jQuery);
   </script>
</f:format.raw>
```

Comment: the only thing that works is to escape the fluid variable declaration like `<f:format.raw>{</f:format.raw>` and `<f:format.raw>}</f:format.raw>` but that is not great to work with.

Answer (score 0):

CDATA sections in fluid are broken since TYPO3 v8 switched to the standalone fluid parser, which brought the `NamespaceDetectionTemplateProcessor` that is responsible for removing CDATA section content.

See https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid/issues/474